# Why Does Vanilla JavaScript Functions Have to Be Defined in the HTML Panel on JSFiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

I noticed that if I define a JavaScript function in the JS panel and include the function in an onclick attribute in the HTML mark-up, the function is not recognized.  But if I define the same function using opening and closing script tags in the HTML panel like so:

```
<script>
    function myfunction(){
        alert("chow");    
    }
</script>

<button id = "mybutton" onclick = "myfunction()">Click me</button>
```

the function is recognized.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/93D8r/) where function is defined in HTML panel

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/93D8r/1/) where function is defined in JavaScript panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to configure jsFiddle to not wrap the JS code in the `load` or `ready` event handler (which it does by default):

[image]

Otherwise the function will be *local* to those event handlers, not global. To make event handlers defined HTML work, you have to define the function in global scope.

More information can be found [in the documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar).

Comment: Why would the function not be called if one of the two event listeners are specified?  Both the iFrame document and the window object would have finished loading when I click on the button in my example

Comment: If the function is defined *inside* the event handlers, it is local to them, not global. Hence it cannot be found by event handlers you define in HTML. By not wrapping the code, the function is defined in global scope.